# i want the message sync complete of google drive through automated batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, synchronization, unattended-processing

When we upload something google drive its start uploading automatically so i need output after completion of successful uploading.

Normally we get message that sync complete i want that output through batch file

basically i am making files uploading automated through batch files

first upload some files to google drive using robocopy

then wait till sync complete and when sync get complete i need that sync complete message into text file so i can verify that sync get completed successfully

so is there any switch available which gives such kind of output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i try to find solution using google but not find related this question but found some similar questions like    http://superuser.com/questions/807907/how-to-force-a-google-drive-sync-from-windows-7-command-prompt